# linux mint 18.1 wifi problems

Tags: wifi, pci

Hello I'm getting mad about the wifi on my Linux Mint 18.1 system:

`lspci` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 30)
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] (rev a2)
```

op on command `lspci -nn | grep Atheros is:`

```
gh0st@gh0st-Aspire ~ $ lspci -nn | grep Atheros 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
```

I already did follow some help and hints I've found so I did the following:

```
exec sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) git
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" |  tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/20/backports-20151120.tar.gz
tar zxvf backports-20151120.tar.gz
cd backports-20151120
make defconfig-wifi
make
make install
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
cp -r ath10k-firmware/QCA9377 /lib/firmware/ath10k/
cp /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
reboot
```

and still the problem persists:

it works quite good for a few minutes and then stops works for 10-20m. Or when I reboot and disconnect and connect again it works again for a few mins.

Comment: can you add in 1-2 sentences what exactly is not working? We can read the commands you execute but it's not entirely clear what you already tried.

Comment: after 1-2 minutes connected over wifi it stops working and loading pages while still keeps connected with no errors!

Comment: Try to compile the latest backports from [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2016/03/24/)

Comment: Could you explain me how to do so please?

Comment: Starting from `wget` command to `sudo make install` on your question the `wget` should be: `wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2016/03/24/backports-20160324.tar.gz`

Comment: Nothing, didnt work

Comment: Check the installed version of `linux-firmware` : `apt-cache policy linux-firmware`

Answer (score 1):

Lets uninstall the unnecessary changes

```
cd backports-20151120
sudo make uninstall
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
sudo mv firmware-5.bin firmware-5.bin.bak
sudo mv board.bin board.bin.bak
sudo mv board-2.bin board-2.bin.bak
```

Then we will reinstall the linux-firmware package as it might be newer than the files from github

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

These devices don't work very well with power management enabled and a recent change to Network Manager enables power management by default, we can change that with

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Reboot

You should also check `iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|cipher'`
If your connection is using TKIP as encryption it is likely causing problems and you will need to make encryption settings changes on the wireless access point